# MYSQL union display

Tags: php, mysql, union

I'm using a query to search in two tables (tracks and artist):

```
SELECT trackID, title
FROM tracks WHERE title LIKE '%$s%'
LIMIT 5
UNION
SELECT artistID, name
FROM artists WHERE name LIKE '%$s%'
LIMIT 5";
```

I use `mysql_num_rows($result)` to display the result of this query, but I don't know how to display it properly.
 Because I want the output result be different when the row is from artists but keep the same order.

I hope this is clear, Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You want to distinguish between artist row and track row is that you need ?

Comment: Yes, but put them in one big list either way

Comment: see my answer is that you are looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use another column to identify the resultant rows like

```
SELECT trackID AS id, title AS title, 'track' AS result_type
FROM tracks WHERE title LIKE '%$s%'
LIMIT 5
UNION
SELECT artistID AS id, name AS title , 'artist' AS result_type
FROM artists WHERE name LIKE '%$s%'
LIMIT 5;

/* $result= fetch results from query*/
   foreach($result as $row){
     if($row['result_type'] =='track'){
    /*  your code */
     }
     if($row['result_type'] =='artist'){
    /* your code */
     }
   }
```